# How does the salary system for faculty in Canadian universities work?

Tags: professorship, salary, canada

How does the salary system for faculty members in Canadian universities work? Is it usually 8- or 9-monthly based same as in the USA Or 12-monthly?

Also, what do they mean by Taxable Benefits in their salary database (e.g., [Ontario, Ministry of Finance; Public Sector Salary Disclosure for 2013: Universities](http://www.fin.gov.on.ca/en/publications/salarydisclosure/pssd/orgs.php?pageNum_pssd=0&organization=universities&year=2013))?

Comment: I don't know elsewhere, but in Quebec, except McGill university, all teachers are unionized. Then, even at McGill, salaries are for 12months (supplemented by "bonuses" for teaching credits).

Comment: Does it mean that in Quebec, except McGill U, all other universities have 12-monthly salary system for the faculty members? What is bonuses here? Do they get paid for teaching more?

Comment: All universities (with McGill) have 12-monthly salary system. The difference is at McGill every professor deals his own salaries, else they have a ranking and follow the union progression. For the "bonuses", each professor is expected to teach a few classes per year, and at McGill they get roughly 7500$ for every 3credit class taught. And I still have to see one professor asking to teach more then what is required by the department :).

Comment: What does it mean by Taxable Benefits then?

Comment: I saw a note somewhere that it could include tuition waivers for dependents.

Comment: There is a link in this question that might be of interest to you: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/26487/10643

Answer (score 4):

It's actually very straightforward: the salary they list is the salary you get. No 8- or 9-month shenanigans, just what they quote. You might get extra money for teaching (extra) courses, but you don't have to find a way to pay yourself over the summer (indeed, research grant money never goes into the PI's pocket).

Other Taxable Benefits means non-monetary benefits, which might include free or subsidized stuff like memberships (e.g., to a University fitness centre). Senior administrative types (also appointed as professors in some department or other) might get all kinds of non-monetary benefits like a place to live or the use of a car.