# How much do math professors get paid in the United States?

Tags: mathematics, professorship, job, united-states, salary

I have been researching professorship (full tenure) and I have been wondering what these full time professors make?

I am not talking about professors are Harvard, but middle-good universities?

In the United States.

Comment: Country/location?

Comment: USA, I just edited @scaahu

Comment: What has your research shown so far? Which state in the US? With what experience? What is a "middle-good" university - 100th in the world or 500th? What are the other benefits in the package? What sort of professorship - i.e. with what responsibilities? Private or public? Named chair? And what's your **underlying** question - what difference would the answer here make to you?

Comment: This answer http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/32458/546 should be helpful to you.

Answer (score 19):

There are several sources for this data. There are general salary surveys, such as the one done by the *Chronicle of Higher Education*.  These often classify only by rank and type of institution, not by discipline.

There is a more informative discipline-specific survey done by the American Mathematical Society: their [Faculty Salary Report](http://www.ams.org/profession/data/annual-survey/facsal). This lags behind by a year or two while they process the data; the most recently released report when I write this is from 2013. The AMS divides mathematics departments into several groups depending on specialty and whether the department offers a doctorate, master's, or bachelors degree as its highest degree.

For future reference, here are the mean (average) reported salaries for new hire Assistant Professors in the 2013 AMS report. The meaning of each category is described in the report, which has much more detailed information.

- Public, PhD-granting Large: $83,242
- Public, PhD-granting Medium: $72,284
- Public, PhD-granting Small: $67,043
- Private, PhD-granting Large: $88,080
- Private, PhD-granting Small: $75,722
- Applied Math Department, PhD-granting: $81,234
- Statistics Department, PhD-granting: $77,759
- Biostatistics Department, PhD-granting: $88,362
- Master's degree granting: $60,355
- Bachelor's only: $56,217

There is also data available from CUPA-HR (e.g. [2014 Executive Summary)](http://www.cupahr.org/surveys/results.aspx). This organization has much more detailed data, but most of the data is not publicly released (university administrations pay for the data, so they can compare themselves to peers). They do release a summary by field, including mathematics, applied mathematics, and statistics.