# How much research assistant in academia is paid in France

Tags: salary, research-assistantship

Research assistant (with master degree, currently PhD student) in France is hired to make some research related activity (e.g., running psychological experiments with volunteers). How much per hour a research assistant might be paid? I need to know whether it includes social benefits.

Many thanks!

Comment: If you are currently a PhD student in France, and if you are paid by your university ("under contract", « sous contrat »), chances are that you are not allowed to accept another job unless particular conditions are met. You can have a look at https://guide-doctorat.fr/fiches/DoctoratALaLoupe-13.pdf (in French) to know more about that. As for your question… it depends. Just ask, nobody can answer that question but your future employer. Also, if you are currently hired as a PhD student, you probably already have social benefits, and don't need them twice!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In which countries are academic salaries published?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26487/in-which-countries-are-academic-salaries-published)

Comment: In France social benefits are included with any kind of salary, it's mandatory.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! First, please assume that the person is eligible to work. The question is whether for example 2,000 Euro per month is a reasonable salary for the position I described? Note that "research associate" (Ingénieur de recherche) seems to be higher qualification than "research assistant" that I am asking about.

Comment: I don't know from where you are. Be aware that in France you will get 12 months, not 13 or 14. Refer to annual salary and chech out for the taxes.

Comment: @BrainResearcher assuming 2000/month is the net salary, I'd say it's quite good; but I wouldn't be surprised that this is the amount before taxes, in which case it's just ok I guess (btw take into account the typical rent in the city).